# What can I subsitute for Aluminum foil in the oven? I am allergic to Aluminum

Tags: baking

I am allergic to Aluminum and have always had a problem with what else I can use to line baking dishes or pans in the oven and toaster oven. Can you give me an idea of what else might be oven proof for this use? I used to just leave it and scrub like mad but now my arthritis is too bad for that.

Comment: Hi and welcome, how about [parchment paper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchment_paper) or one of the many [cooking sprays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooking_spray)? Did i miss something?

Comment: Wear gloves while handling Aluminium foil, isn't it a skin contact allergy?

Comment: @Johannes_B Welcome! Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Hi @Cindy The be honest, i would mark this as a non-answer, as there is nothing really to answer the question.

Comment: @Johannes_B Those are reasonable substitutes in at least some cases, so it certainly would answer the question. Simple answers are still answers, and we'd really prefer them posted as answers. (And we'd also prefer you don't flag simple answers as non-answers...)

Comment: @Jefromi I don't want to mess up this Q/A -> http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17996024#17996024

Answer (score 2):

[Oven bags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oven_bag) will take the heat:

> The plastic used for manufacture of the oven bag must be chosen so that it will not melt at the temperature during cooking and thus spoil the food. To this end, many oven bags are formed from a special heat resistant nylon.

I'm not having any luck finding the material in a convenient roll form, but [Reynolds](http://www.reynoldskitchens.com/products/oven-bags/) and [other manufacturers](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oven%20bags%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb) make the bags in a variety of sizes, some of which are large enough to be cut up and line your dishes and pans.

Answer (score 2):

As the goal is ease of cleanup, and not holding in steam, you may want to consider changing your vessels rather than in lining them:

- Ceramic dishes are easier to clean up than metal pans.  They can also be soaked for long times to loosen up any thing that might get baked on.  If you haven't already made the switch, you may want to consider it.
- You can get silicone pans (bread pans, muffin pans, etc.), but remember that you'll want to support them with a metal sheet pan underneath.  They're also not rate for extremely high temperatures, so you likely don't want to slip them under a broiler.

You can also find silicone baking sheets which work well for cookies, but don't necessarily help with cleanup for spills (the liquid gets around the sheet, and still bakes onto the pan).  Silicone paper (ie, parchment paper) can have the same problem; if you want to use if for cleanup purposes, you need to cut it oversized, then fold in the corners; do not simply cut a base to fit in, then cut the sides seperately.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Cookina Cuisine](http://cookina.co/products/cookina-cuisine/) reusable baking sheet and the [Cookina Gard](http://cookina.co/products/cookina-gard/) oven protector?